# How do I use the Ruby gRPC health check library

Tags: ruby, grpc, kubernetes-health-check

I need to implement gRPC health check so I can use my gRPC API in Kubernetes.

I've worked out that I need to put the [health checking proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.15.0/doc/health-checking.md) file in my server, and implement it.

It looks like there's [a library](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/grpc/Grpc/Health/Checker) that already implements it for Ruby, but I can't work out how to use it.

I've got the 'grpc' gem installed and I've tried this:

```
require 'grpc/health/checker'

# Implement health service.
health_svc = Grpc::Health::Checker.new
health_svc.add_status("plugin", Grpc::Health::V1::HealthCheckResponse::
ServingStatus::SERVING)
```

And I've tried this:

```
require 'health_check_services_pb'

class HealthCheckService < Grpc::Health::V1::Health::Service
  def check(req, req_view)
    checker = Grpc::Health::Checker.new
    checker.check(req, req_view)
  end
end
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Grpc::Health::Checker
```

So how do I use the library (other than copy all the library code from GitHub into my server)?

Comment: Did you check this: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/10/01/health-checking-grpc-servers-on-kubernetes/ ?

Comment: @unludo yes, I did check that

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the correct requires for the protobufs are

```
require 'grpc/health/v1/health_pb'
require 'grpc/health/v1/health_services_pb'
```

as found in [checker_spec.rb](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/618a3f561d4a93f263cca23abad086ed8f4d5e86/src/ruby/spec/pb/health/checker_spec.rb#L16)